# Snakemake remote: Keyerrpr

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I need to download some file from remote http:
If I  use  to download bz2 or pdf I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 522, in snakemake
    cluster_status=cluster_status)
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 586, in execute
    success = scheduler.schedule()
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 283, in schedule
    self.run(job)
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 300, in run
    error_callback=self._error)
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 327, in run
    job.prepare()
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 523, in prepare
    self.download_remote_input()
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 498, in download_remote_input
    f.download_from_remote()
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 270, in download_from_remote
    self.remote_object.download()
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/remote/HTTP.py", line 162, in download
    if not self.name.endswith(".gz") and httpr.headers["Content-Encoding"] == "gzip":
  File "/home/ktule/miniconda2/envs/snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'content-encoding
```

I use the 
snakemake --version
4.6.0

and

```
from snakemake.remote.HTTP import RemoteProvider as HTTPRemoteProvider

HTTP = HTTPRemoteProvider()
rule all:
    input:
        HTTP.remote("http://....../tools/2015-10-somatic_variant_calling_and_denovo.pdf", keep_local=True)
    output:
        "2015-10-somatic_variant_calling_and_denovo.pdf"
    run:
        shell("mv {input} {output}")
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this has been fixed recently. Either try the latest version, or wait a few days for me to release the next version. Sorry for the inconvenience!